# Export Map Schema\Metadata

Tags: arcmap

I've been digging around, but I can't seem to find out if it's possible.

I create a series of maps for a client and I need to document all the specifications in the map. So I need to create a spreadsheet/word doc of all the properties set in each layer (i.e. symbology colors, border thickness, definitions queries, label expressions, source, coordinate system...basically all the settings in the layers properties dialogue box) Same thing for the data frame properties settings.

Is there a function in ArcMap to do this?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/from_the_Table_of_Contents_window/003t0000001t000000/

Comment: So, all the map metadata, but isn't this information something you would actually create before creating the map, and than just change it as you go if needed? Unfortunately Arcgis doesn't offer anything like that, not that i know of. Nor does any other software that i can think of.

Comment: The information is available but it will need to be pro-grammatically created in custom metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not meet all your requirements but I suspect that it may meet many of them:

[**X-ray Add-In for ArcMap**](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=596204091a9147f9b609a6537a51d0d1) will help you develop and refine map documents by:

- Documenting the layer and their properties contained in each map document
- Documenting the source of each layer in a map document
- Documenting label properties for each layer in a map document
- Analyzing the differences between two map documents
- Synchronizing layer aliases with changes made to field aliases in the source (GDB)
- Localizing layer names and descriptions in your map document
- Editing the layer properties in a simple spreadsheet

It is FREE and was demonstrated by Scott Campbell of Eagle Technologies at the Esri Asia-Pacific User Conference in New Zealand earlier this week - which is why it came quickly to mind.

Comment: This is great. Pretty much what I was looking for!